# (XSLT 2.0) Dynamic number in name of variable in for-each

Tags: xml, xslt, svg, xslt-2.0

I have these variables:

```
<xsl:variable name="dystrybutor1" select="count(//gra[dystrybutor='Atari'])"/>
<xsl:variable name="dystrybutor2" select="count(//gra[dystrybutor='CD Projekt'])"/>
<xsl:variable name="dystrybutor3" select="count(//gra[dystrybutor='Cenega'])"/>
<xsl:variable name="dystrybutor4" select="count(//gra[dystrybutor='Double Fine'])"/>
<xsl:variable name="dystrybutor5" select="count(//gra[dystrybutor='Electronic Arts'])"/>
<xsl:variable name="dystrybutor6" select="count(//gra[dystrybutor='LEM'])"/>
<xsl:variable name="dystrybutor7" select="count(//gra[dystrybutor='Rockstar Games'])"/>
```

And these instructions:

```
<text x="85" y="{(($max)-(80*$dystrybutor1))+5}"><xsl:value-of select="$dystrybutor1"/></text>
<text x="85" y="{(($max)-(80*$dystrybutor2))+5}"><xsl:value-of select="$dystrybutor2"/></text>
<text x="85" y="{(($max)-(80*$dystrybutor3))+5}"><xsl:value-of select="$dystrybutor3"/></text>
<text x="85" y="{(($max)-(80*$dystrybutor4))+5}"><xsl:value-of select="$dystrybutor4"/></text>
<text x="85" y="{(($max)-(80*$dystrybutor5))+5}"><xsl:value-of select="$dystrybutor5"/></text>
<text x="85" y="{(($max)-(80*$dystrybutor6))+5}"><xsl:value-of select="$dystrybutor6"/></text>
<text x="85" y="{(($max)-(80*$dystrybutor7))+5}"><xsl:value-of select="$dystrybutor7"/></text>
```

Is it possible to make for-each with incrementation of number in variable name?
Something like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="1 to 7"><text x="85" y="{(($max)-(80*$dystrybutor{NUMBER}))+5}"><xsl:value-of select="$dystrybutor{NUMBER}"/>[some instruction to increment NUMBER]</text></xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reorganize your code to declare one variable with a sequence of those values

```
<xsl:variable name="distributors"
  select="count(//gra[dystrybutor='Atari']),
          count(//gra[dystrybutor='CD Projekt']),
          count(//gra[dystrybutor='Cenega']), 
          count(//gra[dystrybutor='Double Fine']),
          count(//gra[dystrybutor='Electronic Arts']),
          count(//gra[dystrybutor='LEM']),
          count(//gra[dystrybutor='Rockstar Games'])"/>
```

and then process those values

```
<xsl:for-each select="$distributors">
  <text x="85" y="{(($max)-(80 * .))+5}">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </text>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Does it work now that I have spelled out the declaration of the variable? If not then please show us a minimal but complete snippet of the XML so that we have something to work with to create a working sample.

Comment: In http://xsltransform.net/94rmq6r I don't get an error, obviously I had to make up the input data.

Comment: It's works now, I just used wrong XSLT Validator. Thx!